# Downloading Oracle Glassfish on Ubuntu Server

Tags: redirect, download, glassfish, amazon-ec2, wget

I have an Ubuntu natty server running on Amazon EC2. My problem is that I'm trying to download Oracle Glassfish 3.1.1 however I can't get the file because it redirects to another url. It ends up downloading a 2 kb html file and saving it as the glassfish.sh file.

When I check the content of the html file it seems the login part is failing.

I've tried `wget --http-user="USER" --http-password="PASSWORD" url`

Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading from Oracle with wget is not trivial, because Oracle requires that you accept to the license agreement which in turn is statefully stored.
If you have no way of getting the file  from somewhere else I'd recommend using one of the text based browsers, elinks or w3m.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in the commercial distribution or the open source distribution?  Putting Oracle GlassFish Server into production requires a commercial license.  You can download the open source distribution from here: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.1-final.html